# My SQl Said #1067 - Invalid default value for 'user_registered'

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1067

### Table structure for table `wpvd_users`

```
CREATE TABLE `wpvd_users` (  `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
`user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  `user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  `user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  `user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),  `user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
`user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
`display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '') 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of sql_modes. Please check your current sql_modes by command:

```sql
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

And remove the sql_mode "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE" to make it work. This is the default sql_mode in mysql new versions.

You can set sql_mode globally as root by command:

```sql
set global sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```